# RHEL and Mysql: disadvantages of having everything under one partition?

Tags: linux, mysql

RAID 10 setup.
So apparently one of my clients has his RAID 10 Mysql server all under one parition with RHEL 5 64-bit.
There is only / , /tmp, /boot and swap.
The MySQL datadir is in the / parition (in /opt).
What are the disadvantages of having this setup?

Comment: Anyone else have any input?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the performance implications depending on how the underlying disks are configured.

MySQL can fill up / which can then cause problems for the entire system (rather than just the MySQL process) and make it harder to fix than it would be if MySQL was contained on a separate partition.

Answer (score -2):

The only two disadvantages I can think of are:

1. that the OS's disk IO can consume disk IO needed by the MySQL instance.  (would only be a problem if MySQL load is extremely heavy or the OS tries to do something very disk intensive... the opposite could become non-responsive)
2. Too many disks being used.  If you really want mysql performance, consider implementing memcache to reduce unnecessary hits on the disk... or switch to using SSD and/or hybrid platter/ssd drives.  I am not a fan of using striping to gain performance... as you lose all of that performance when a disk fails... and while rebuilding a stripe reduces performance even further.  More disks also means more points of failure.  Use multiple disks for redundancy... not performance.

Comment: I think we are not talking about multiple disks just about multiple partitions

Comment: And also, performance is most certainly a consideration when considering your disk geography.